# Help files open in two browsers

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

In our application, when you go to "Menu > Help...", it opens our help files in Internet Explorer, which is the desirable effect. However, we have the shortcut key "F1" set to open the help files as well. It still opens the help in Internet Explorer... but it also opens them up at the same time in the user's default web browser!

Here is the code in the event method that opens the web browser:

```
Private Sub menuHelpHelp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles menuHelpHelp.Click

      Dim temp As String = String.Format("{0}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles))
      Dim temp2 As String = String.Format("{0}", Globals.HelpFilePath)
      If Not System.IO.File.Exists(temp2) 
         MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Could not find index.html, run ""help_zip.exe"" inside the Doc folder as an Administrator to restore the help system (make sure to overwrite all files when asked!)"))
      Else
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(temp, temp2)
      End If
   End Sub
```

If I step through the code after clicking the Help menu item, IE opens as intended when I hit the "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(temp, temp2)" line. However, when I do the same thing after pressing F1, it opens first in the user's default browser, and then in IE second. Any ideas? The code in this part of the application is written in VB.NET, and the application is a .NET 3.5 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, have you tried binding the action to another button to see if the problem still exists? Switch it from F1 to F2, see if it still happens. Almost certainly will, unless there's some code in your program which you forgot about that's causing problems.

**EDIT**
You appear to be setting a global variable for your help path.. which means the default F1 Help would likely load the correct file. So I'd go with the "F1 is still bound to the default Help action." You'll need to unbind it.

Comment: I have not tried that, I will try switching the shortcut and see if that helps. It's just strange that it would do anything else with that second parameter in Process.Start before it performed the correct action.

Comment: Well this is weird. Changing the shortcut to "Ctrl + H" did the correct action, same thing with "F2".

Comment: What is also strange is that even when I change the shortcut to another key, F1 still brings the help up in another window. It seems that somewhere else something is binding F1 to just launch index.html on its own.

Comment: Two things I can think of off the top of my head:
A) F1 is the default help button and is already bound to something.
B) You have legacy code somewhere that's messing you up.

Comment: The thing is, anywhere else that the help path would have been referenced in the past, shouldn't be launching that. We recently moved from using a CHM file which was loaded using a dedicated class in the .NET framework to load. So .NET shouldn't be aware of this new help file at all.

Comment: Actually... I think I just figured out what the problem is. I'll post if my suspicions are true.

Comment: You appear to be setting a global variable for your help path.. which means the default F1 Help would likely load the correct file. So I'd go with the "F1 is still bound to the default Help action." You'll need to unbind it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I just noticed, and HelpProvider is using it as well. Since there are a ton of references to this variable though, I'm going to see if I can either get rid of HelpProvider or tweak it to disable the shortcut.

Comment: One website I stumbled onto suggested adjusting the keyboard scheme, under Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. I'm not sure if this would solve your problem as I've never tried it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not looking like Visual Studio will allow me to disable HelpProvider, save for it I want to edit the designer file by hand. I will give that a shot though.